Power Apps Combo Box Button SharePoint
I am developing a program in Power Apps that allows users to self-select subscriptions from a Combo Box. In my system there are two SharePoint sheets:
The "Benutzerdaten" sheet, which contains:

ID (Primary Key)
UserID (defined by the code Office365-Benutzer.MyProfileV2().mailNickname)
abo_id (foreign key linking the user to a subscription or subscriptions)

The "Abonnementen" sheet, which contains:

ID (Primary Key)
Titel (Subscription Title)


How can I organize the ComboBox and the "Accept" button so that the selected subscriptions are stored in the database taking into account the dependencies between tables?
When I write the corresponding code, I get the following error.

The type of this argument "abo_id" does not match the expected type "Table". Type "Number" was found.

In SharePoint the dependencies are set correctly and if I assign a subscription to a user in the "Benutzerdaten" sheet, it is assigned to him.
My code:
    ForAll(ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems;
        Patch(Benutzerdaten;
            Defaults(Benutzerdaten); {
                Titel: 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname;
                abo_id: LookUp(Abonnementen; Titel = ThisRecord.Titel; ID)
            }
        )
    )

I have also tried the following code variations:
ForAll(
    ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems,
    Patch(
        Benutzerdaten,
        Defaults(Benutzerdaten),
        {
            UserID: 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname,
            abo_id: Table({Value: LookUp(Abonnementen, Titel = ThisRecord.Titel, ID)})
        }
    )
)

And
ForAll(
    ComboBox_Abonnementen.SelectedItems,
    Patch(
        Benutzerdaten,
        Defaults(Benutzerdaten),
        {
            Titel: 'Office365-Benutzer'.MyProfileV2().mailNickname,
            abo_id: Table({Id: LookUp(Abonnementen, Titel = ThisRecord.Titel, ID)})
        }
    )
)

Thanks‌‌.
